# How can I write a function in Express that can return JSON when called as an API, but also be called internally without Axios/Fetch?

Tags: node.js, express

Not even sure the best way to describe it, but basically I have a function in an Express Controller, available at /api/lookupJobName which takes query param Q, which is a number, and then does some background work (connects to Salesforce, looks up the job number, gets it's actual name) and returns a json object like this:

```
oppName = { name: "whateverCameBack" }
res.json(oppName)
```

Pretty straightforward, and I created it that way because it gets called from some client-side JS when they enter a number in a form.

Now I'm further along in the project and I need to quickly grab a job name from a job number again, but it's all server-side. I don't think it makes sense to re-write what is essentially the same code, or to use Axios to call the function against my own API (it's extra traffic, and get's a bit messy needing a proxy), but I can't just call the module directly because it throws an error because I'm using res.json to send back the data.

Can I re-use the code from the API or do I need to write a copy of it for my specific purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly then you can use a module! This is assuming your secondary use is on the same server. If it isn't then you would need to do something else.

```js
// fn.js
module.exports = function doStuff(jobId) {
  const whateverCameBack = doSomething(jobId);
  return { name: whateverCameBack }
}

// app.js
var doStuff = require('./fn');
app.get('api/jobs/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  doStuff(req.params.id)
    .then(x => res.json(x)) // assuming it's async
    .then(next);
});

// somewhere else in server
var doStuff = require('./fn');
doStuff(jobId).then(oppName => // whatever);
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the code sample - I think this is exactly what I need, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to write a module that exports the core functionality as a simple function. This module in turn could be called by

1. your express api
2. a cli tool of your making (for example)

So your api and the cli are just thin layers around the actual functionality, which shouldn't know anything about cli or express.